# difference between linear modulation and non-linear modulation scheme?

Tags: modulation, linear

As shown in title: what's the difference between linear modulation and non-linear modulation scheme?

I can not find the formal definition of this.
And there is a different determination for the FSK modulation (linear and non-linear).

[FSK is non-linear](http://www.edaboard.com/thread99077.html)

[FSK is linear and can be classified using likely-hood ratio function](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/4105970/4167651/04167652.pdf)

While the GMSK is non-linear according to the searched results, however I don't know why.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://course.sdu.edu.cn/G2S/eWebEditor/uploadfile/20121213093025493.pdf) source:

Digital modulation techniques are classified as linear if:

- The amplitude of the transmitted signal varies linearly with the modulating *digital* signal, \$m(t)\$.
- They usually do not have a constant envelope
- They are more spectral efficient.
- Poor power efficiency

The only other "linearity"-reference I could find was in the same course slides:

For Frequency Modulation, the relationship between received power and quality is *non-linear* (Rapid increase in quality for an increase in received power).

For Amplitude Modulation there is a linear relationship between the received signal quality and received signal power.

But I am not totally convinced that this is at the basis of the definition (I'm also not totally unconvinced).

IMHO, I think they started out calling the AM scheme linear, as \$AM(a\cdot V_{in}) = a\cdot AM(V_{in})\$, and then they started playing with the phase ((Q)PSK) and just labeled it as linear as well, while it isn't strictly true.

[EDIT] I also found [this](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/94312-1.php) which seems to support my last remark.